# PubNub stop publishing

Tags: sockets, publish, publish-subscribe, pubnub

In using PubNub when I do a publish why does it start a continuous loop?
Programs should end once the function is done. 
But after the publish message is sent, the publish program continues to run, like it is waiting for something else.

Here is my code

```java
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import com.pubnub.api.*;

import org.json.*;

public class UserRegister {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Pubnub pubnub_pub = new Pubnub("pub-c-3192165c-...", "sub-c-7debcf5c-...");

        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                System.out.println(error.toString());
            }
        };

        String encMessage="";
        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        try {

            System.out.println("user reg");
            message.put("CMD", "USER_REGISTER");
            message.put("EMAIL", "jabali2@jabali.in");
            message.put("PASSWORD", "1123");
            message.put("TIMESTAMP", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            encMessage = new MyEncrypt().encrypt(message.toString());

        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pubnub_pub.publish("jabali_channel_101", encMessage, callback);
    }
}
```

Shouldnt the program stop once it finishes publishing?
Its not getting stuck in a loop somewhere either. I can see the output in the PubNub console and in my subscriber. Also I can write what ever I want after the publish statement and it continues like a normal program.  
Except for the fact that it never ends on its own 
Can any one explain what is going on?

Comment: I can understand subscribe running in an infinite loop. It needs to keep listening on a channel. But once the publish is done, it makes no sense to have it running. Is there a way I can stop it?

Comment: Can you enable logging (use the debug jar), capture this behavior and send to support@pubnub.com ? and you shouldn't expose your pub key or your sub key to the public.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

`pubnub_pub.stop();`

This will terminate the thread itself after publishing.

Comment: Simply nice answer @iaL ... that helped me...!! thanks..!!